# My AMD radeon 6470M is detected but still doesn't work. Some solutions?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I have a laptop HP Pavilion g6-1217sg with Intel i5-2430M and a catty **AMD 6470M**.
The Kubuntu version is the last 17.04.

The follow commands and results would show how the system still use the Intel but not the AMD:

```
$ lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core     Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] (rev ff)
```

,

```
$ sudo lspci -v -s 01:00.0

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.    [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    DeviceName: ATI SEYMOUR XT
    !!! Unknown header type 7f
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

,

```
$ sudo lshw -class display

  *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:30 memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff     ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I am not able to run the VGA. I have tried many guides online but the system still use the intel graphic.

According the manual this SO should has integrated AMD driver able to run many Radeon VGA, like the 6470m.  However, the VGA is detected but not works.

I have tried to install the AMD driver but they don't installing correctly.

Someone who has this VGA and has solved this problem could help me, please ?

Thanks who could help me.